# In Starcraft II, do the armory upgrades apply to hero/mercenary units as well?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I purchase an upgrade for the firebats or marines from the armory on the Hyperion, will the heroes/mercenary units also receieve the upgrade bonus or are their stats unaffected?

Comment: I thought there were no more firebats?

Comment: @C. Ross, nope, they're still there. According to the wiki (http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Firebat), they were at one point removed.

Comment: @C. Ross Firebats and other units not in the multiplayer are still available in single player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least *some* Hero units *are* affected.

It's great fun when you have an Odin (Mega-thor) walking around with +2 Weapons, dealing 48 x2 damage a shot.

Edit: Oh wait, you're not talking about the in-mission armory.

I know they get anything you research from an engineering bay or armory, not sure about credits-bought upgrades. Inclined to say "no" though.

**UPDATE:** At least in the instance of the marine mercenaries, they will receive the Combat Shield and Stimpacks upgrades when you buy them for your marines. It serves to follow that other armory purchases affect the mercs as well.

Comment: Yeah, I think he's talking about the upgrades at the armory on the battlecruiser.

Comment: yes, I am. Sorry, I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very much yes.

If you're referring to the armory building in-game. Then the upgrades there will apply to the mercenary units that would normally be affected by them, like the Thors.

If you're referring to the armory on the hyperion, then yes, upgrades (like stimpack) get applied to the mercenary marines in game.

(Updated)
(Tested)

Comment: Are you sure, I'm almost positive my mercenary marines had stim.

Comment: No, I'm not sure, but I did check that specifically.

Comment: @McKay I'm going to double check this when I get home just to convince myself.

Comment: @tzenes yeah, me too.

Comment: @McKay, Tzenes, others. I can confirm that after purchasing Stimpacks, the Marine Mercenaries got the ability to use them.

Comment: @Raven I thought so